# PHP sessions not working with memcached

Tags: php, apache, memcached

I am trying to setup memcached to allow session sharing on 2 load balanced Apache servers - in my php.ini I have:

Node 1

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "tcp://NODE1_IP:11211"
```

and

Node 2

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "tcp://NODE2_IP:11211"
```

In /etc/sysconfig/memcached, I have:

```
PORT="11211"
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="1024"
CACHESIZE="64"
OPTIONS="-l 127.0.0.1"
```

In phpinfo I have:

```
session.save_handler    memcached   memcached
session.save_path   tcp://NODE1_IP:11211    tcp://NODE1_IP:11211
```

When I login to my application I have session_start on the login page and on the page which checks if the user is logged in but when I:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Nothing gets shown as the session looks like it is not being set.

One thing of note is that in phpinfo I see at the top of the session section, these lines:

```
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary wddx
```

Registered save handlers lists files and user but nothing about memcached - might that be why this is not working? How can I change/add to that?

Should the node1_ip be the public or private IP or doesn't it matter?

I can telnet to localhost 11211 but not to NODE1_IP 11211 - get connected refused. Port 11211 is open - tried changing /etc/sysconfig/memcached to "-l NODE1_IP:11211" but still get connection refused

If I change the options in /etc/sysconfig/memcached to nothing i.e. OPTIONS "" then I can telnet to NODE1_IP 11211 so it appears the format of what I am putting into memcached config is wrong?

Is there anything else I need to do? I have tried changing the save paths, adding and removing tcp, using 127.0.0.1, using actual IP addresses, using all the IP addresses seperated with a comma but still cannot get this to work.

Comment: How do you sync memcached on NODE1_IP and NODE2_IP?

Comment: Have tried setting session.save_path = "tcp://NODE1_IP:11211, tcp://NODE2_IP:11211" on both nodes as well as in OPTIONS in /etc/sysconfig/memcached but this doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: @bhttoan I had a real nightmare getting memcached to work behind my load balancer and ended up switching to redis in the end. I had an easy time of it because my application was built with Laravel. Out of interest, are you using a framework at all?

Comment: Try to point both servers to the same memcached instance to confirm the handler works. Write something to the session, and check `stats items` returns the keys.

Comment: iirc `save_path` should be a `host:port`. Try `session.save_path = "NODE1_IP:11211"` without tcp.

Comment: also confirm memcached is reachable from apache hosts: `telnet NODE1_IP 11211`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have:

```
session.save_handler = memcached
```

It means you are using memcache**D** extension and not memcache one.

And in that case, the config should be written **without** the *tcp://* protocol:

```
session.save_path NODE1_IP:11211
```

*session.save_path=tcp://NODE1_IP:11211* is for the **memcache** extension, without "d" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using sticky sessions on load balancer, and cannot guaranty requests from the same client are served by the same apache.

`OPTIONS="-l 127.0.0.1"` tells memcached to listen on local loopback only, i.e. it is not accessible from anywhere but localhost. You need to change that to listen on the private network interface (be sure it is not publicly accessible from the internet).

To keep session available on both apache servers, you need to sync memcached. The simplest way is to replicate all data by pointing `save_path` to both servers, and set session_redundancy to 3:

```
session.save_path = "tcp://NODE1_IP:11211, tcp://NODE2_IP:11211"
memcache.allow_failover=1
memcache.session_redundancy=3
```

so the session will be saved to both memcached servers.

If you don't want to sacrifice memory for redundancy, leave only 1 memcached running, and point both apache servers to it.

**EDIT :**

php_memcache library should be installed, e.g. for debian distros:

php 5.x: `apt-get install php5-memcache`

php 7.x: `apt-get install php-memcache`

Comment: Thanks for the answer - tried all of that to no avail. Still do not get the session created when I login. In both php.ini and /etc/sysconfig/memcached I set the IP to the private network addresses, is that correct or should the save_path be public IP addresses?

Comment: Also in phpinfo I have "Registered save handlers files user" under Sessions - does it need any other option to work with memcache?

Comment: Yes, if php_memcache is installed, the Registered save handlers should be "files user memcache"

Comment: php -m shows both memcache and memcached - assume that means it is installed?

Comment: That's fair assumption. Does cli `php -i | grep "Registered save handlers"` shows files and user only?

Comment: It shows Registered save handlers => files user memcache memcached

Comment: Not exactly what phpinfo() says, huh? Either your php-cli config differs from php-apache ones, or you did not reboot apache after installing php. Or it might be different php versions at all. check how mod_php is configured in apache.

Comment: Where is that setting configured?

Comment: For cli `php -i | grep ".ini"`, for web - on the top of phpinfo() output. Search for "Loaded Configuration File" and "Additional .ini files".